# In personification, the vehicle is always _____

Tags: meaning, personification

personification - the attribution of human nature or character to animals, inanimate objects, or abstract notions, especially as a rhetorical figure. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/personification

what is the vehicle in personification? Not so sure what this means, I understand vehicle in metaphors but not in personification.

Comment: Can you give us the full sentence or paragraph this comes from please?

Comment: If you don’t understand it even with context, how are we supposed to understand it _without_ any context? For all we know, the answer could be, “In personification, the vehicle is always a BMW”.

Comment: People do say "I've just had my car serviced, _she_ goes like a dream now". Is this what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

> - **Obviously, in personification the vehicle is always a human being, otherwise it wouldn't be personification** You give human characteristics, such as the ability to think and speak, to animals, plants, and inanimate objects.  A teapot can talk and act like a human being, for example. Or a cat and a mouse have most human characteristics.  **There is always a lot of personification in cartoons, where the vehicle is always human.**

Then again, **a person as a vehicle**, is a completely different matter:

A person is said to be a vehicle when it transmits something (a message, a thought, a secret, or even a disease) to someone else, or plays a role devised by another, with a specific objective in mind.

> - vehicle - "a medium through which something is transmitted, expressed, or accomplished: His novels are a vehicle for his political views." -  [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vehicle)

Examples in literature:

I thought she was only **a vehicle for the plot**, either to fill the slot for innocent human girl caught between the forces of evil, or love triangle ...

Especially as she was **only a vehicle** through which he introduced us to Norman Bates.

the ferocity and intensity of his assault seemed to her a pursuit in which **she was only a vehicle.**

He was **a vehicle of divine, supernatural revelation** from God to man, from heaven to earth.

Comment: Yup. I'd say the "a person as a vehicle" usage is just a metaphor alluding to the ability of vehicles to *transport* things. It's no more an example of "personification" than, say, *kingpin* in a car's steering rack.

Comment: I have no idea what’s going on here, so maybe I should just get some coffee, or go back to bed, or something.  But could this *possibly* be a reference to works of fiction like [*My Mother the Car*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Mother_the_Car), [*Christine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_(1983_film)), and [*The Little Engine That Could*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Engine_That_Could), where actual vehicles (machines for transporting people) are imbued with human characteristics?